# Access properties of another view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I made a timer component for my app (in a seperate view), and I need to toggle the "timerRunning" bool from my GameView when the NEXT button is pressed.

However, it says that it cannot find the timerRunning in the scope.

How can I easily access the timerRunning property from another view

```
struct GameView: View {
    
    @State private var cardNumber = 0
    @State var showGameView: Bool
    let sequence = (0..<cardArray.count).shuffled()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            BackgroundComponent()
            
            VStack
            {
                
                Spacer()
                
                TimerComponent()
                
                Spacer()
                
                CardComponent(cardDifficulty: cardArray[sequence[cardNumber]].difficulty, cardTitle: cardArray[sequence[cardNumber]].title, cardNotes: cardArray[sequence[cardNumber]].notes)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button {
                    dealCard()
                    timerRunning = true
                    SoundManager.instance.player?.stop()
                    
                } label: {
                    PrimaryButton(text: "NEXT")
                }
                
              }
    

struct TimerComponent: View {
    
    @State  var countdownTimer = 60
    @State  var timerRunning = true
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(timerRunning == true ? "\(countdownTimer)" : "Time's up!")
            .onReceive(timer){ _ in
                if countdownTimer > 0 && timerRunning {
                    countdownTimer -= 1
                    if countdownTimer == 10 {
                        SoundManager.instance.playSound(sound: .flatline)
                    }
                } else if countdownTimer == 0 {
                    timerRunning = false
                    countdownTimer = -1
                }
            }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`timerRunning` should be a `@State` in `GameView`, and a `@Binding` in `TimerComponent`. This allows `GameView` to "control" the `TimerComponent`.

```
struct GameView: View {
    @State var timerRunning = true
    ...

        // pass the state to TimerComponent like this
        TimerComponent(timerRunning : $timerRunning)

        ...

        Button {
            dealCard()
            // setting this changes the timerRunning property in TimerComponent too!
            timerRunning = true
    ...
}
```

```
struct TimerComponent: View {
    ...

    @Binding var timerRunning: Bool

    ...
}
```